# Update recibe varias filas, Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo una tabla donde se organizan las actividades de un curso:
id, id_curso, id_actividad, order

Necesito crear un servicio para actualiza dicho orden, donde reciba el id de la tabla (es un update) y el campo order

no tengo claro el código a utilizar para recibir este array de datos, me pueden ayudar por favor?

El código va en un controlador, ya tengo los modelos. Solo requiero del código para recibir dicho array.

en el servicio recibo el id del curso en la url

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{

}
```

este es un ejemplo de lo que puedo recibir:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Primero traer todas las filas en el index.

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
  $actividades = Actividad::all();

  return view('actividad.index',compact("actividades"));
}
```

Luego desde la vista index al seleccionar el que querés modificar envías al método edit del controlador que hace esto:

```
public function edit(Actividad $actividad)
{
  return view('actividad.edit', compact("actividad"));
}
```

Luego en la vista de modificación editas y envías las modificaciones al método update, que contiene algo así si recibís el id:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
  $actividad = Actividad::find($id);
  $actividad->order = $request->input('order');
  $actividad->save();

  return redirect()
    ->route('actividades.show',['actividad' => $actividad])
    ->with('message','Actividad Actualizada');
}
```

Donde $request->input('order'); es el valor modificado que viene de la vista donde editaste. Saludos.

Comment: Mil gracias, pero la idea no es editar una actividad. La idea es editar el orden de varias actividades en un curso, por eso indico que recibo un array (n líneas para actualizar en la tabla)

Comment: Está bien, recibís la tabla completa, con todas las actividades, y querés modificar el órden, una especie de cola de espera... pero para modificarlas tenes que hacerlo individualmente, actividad por actividad... de lo contrario, si estás pensando en algo más interactivo donde modificas una y afecta el orden de las otras, reactualizando todo, ya es un desarrollo que va más allá de lo que has descripto, depende de reglas, que pasa cuando moves una, como se reordenan las otras, etc.